# Testing outlet for grounding caused breaker to trip

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, afci

I searched the forum and could not find something similar. Apologies if this has already been asked.

I was watching YouTube videos explaining how to test outlets and in the videos testing Hot to Ground gave a reading of ~120V meaning there was a safe path back to the panel.

When I did the same thing in my house by taking the black lead connected to the COM port on the multimeter and putting it on the Ground hole of the outlet, then taking the red lead connected to the V port on the multimeter to the Hot side of the outlet, it caused the breaker to trip at the panel. The breaker is an Arc Fault breaker that was installed less than 6 months ago when the breakers were upgraded after moving in to this new to me house.

My question is, **Does the Arc Fault Breaker consider this Hot to Ground test an Arc and trip as expected or do I have a grounding issue?**

Thank you.

Comment: If you re-write your question as: "I created an earth fault, why did my breaker trip?" what do you think?

Comment: Lots of possibilities: 1 - Does your breaker have any diagnostic that tells you whether a trip is an Arc Fault vs. a Ground Fault vs. Overcurrent/Short? 2 - If you test Hot to Neutral, what do you get? If you test Neutral to Ground, what do you get? If Hot/Neutral ~120V and Neutral/Ground = 0 then I suspect Hot/Ground = ground fault (i.e., breaker doing its job). But that's just a guess.; What model multimeter?

Comment: it could have sparked as you made contact. try it hooked up before turning the breaker on.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- It just has one light that indicates arc fault. It's a Siemens Q1515AFC breaker. 2. Hot to Neutral is 120, Neutral to Ground is 0. Since this is not a Ground Fault Breaker or a Combination Ground and Arc Fault Breaker, I was not expecting it to trip by doing Hot to Ground. I was expecting the same result as all the videos. The multimeter is a Klein Tools MM700 and I was running it in LoZ mode since I have experiences ghost voltage when running in regular mode V mode.

Comment: @dandavis that's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if the breaker would be that sensitive to trip. I was just expecting a different result from the test.

Comment: I suspect that even though it is not a GF breaker per se, it may still be tripping on that, sort of like a GF. AF detection is (relatively speaking) extremely complex compared to GF (simple comparison) and overcurrent (thermal or magnetic).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you very much for the information. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The other thing you can do **only on neutral to ground** is to check continuity. 0V neutral to ground could mean "no voltage" but could also mean "no connection" - I checked on my tester (Klein MM300) and it shows no difference in AC V between "not connected to anything (leads hanging in the air) and "connected together" (neutral to ground) but continuity test correctly beeps on neutral to ground.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact doing a neutral to ground continuity does beep so that is good.

Comment: I use to test them exactly the same way. My voltage tester was a Square D solenoid type which did draw a few ma. If the meter has an analog scale I would expect this to be normal. You could test it on other circuits in your home as a comparason.

Comment: @Gil all the circuits in the house are on Arc Fault Breaker or Combination Ground / Arc Fault breakers with the exception of the Air Conditioning circuits. So most likely testing on another circuit will have the same result.

Comment: That is what I was assuming, a combo unit. The breaker tripped as expected, the meter plus leakage exceeded about 5mA, the fault trip point. Since I do not have any information on his meter I was trying to get a benchmark by trying it in other circuits to validate consistent results. Thanks for confirming my expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lack of grounding will not trip an arc fault breaker, so it's not a "grounding issue".  I mean your grounding may be a dumpster fire, but it's not going to trip the AFCI if it is.

---

Almost any meter made is too high-impedance to trip a GFCI or AFCI. GFCIs trip on 5mA of ground-fault current flow. Almost all AFCIs take a neutral wire because they are using a GFPE (weak GFCI) operating at 30mA to detect hot-ground and neutral-ground arc faults. I can't imagine any post-1905 voltmeter taking that much current, *but then, yours has a low-Z mode*. How low-Z is it? 30mA seems like a lot because that's 3.6-14.4 watts of heat that has to be disposed of in the meter, but read the instructions - it surely must say.

More likely, your probing touched something BAD, causing a positively spectacular arc flash, tripping the breaker and giving you an eyebrow trim.  The reason you don't remember all that is the Arc Fault breaker canceled all the fun before it began.

Mind you, it may not have been the probe itself. It could be that pushing on the socket pushed a neutral or hot screw into a bare ground wire or side of a metal box. That's what happens when people use backstabs and leave the side screws all the way out lol. If it was a neutral-ground fault, the fireworks would not be even the slightest bit exciting, since the voltage difference is under 1 volt.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate-Monica Thank you for the information. I looked that manual and could not find any info as to how LowZ the multimeter is. I know that backstabs were not used to connect this outlet since I replaced it a while back and the box is plastic. As someone else mentioned it might have sparked as I was getting the red lead into the hot side of the outlet. I just did not spect the breaker to consider that an Arc or be that sensitive to it.

Comment: @Joe it might be an arc if the side screws were loose. NEC 110.14 requires a specific torque if stated on the device.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate-Monica oh I didn't know they required a specific torque. I tighten all the screws to what seemed like a sufficient amount. At least the outlet works when things are plugged in and removed and has not tripped before. I am just glad that it was the breaker doing its job. Thank you for all the info.

Comment: @Joe yeah they took a testing rig to electrician trade shows, and lined up all their electricians and their spouses, and tested who torqued more accurately. Low/correct/high: Electricians 50/25/25, spouses 51/25/24.  LOL fail, and experience doesn't help.  The spec torques are MUCH MUCH more than I've been using in the past. If you cam out the Philips, you're almost tight enough LOL.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate-Monica those a pretty interesting results. I always use a flat head screwdriver because I never really liked how well the Phillips one tighten, it always feel to me that it wasn't enough torque. Glad I was in the right direction without knowing it.